# Access describe-service for ECS Service given service's ARN only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

If given an ECS service ARN (e.g. arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:service/cluster-1/example-service) how do you describe-service or similar?

Options I can see are:

- manually parsing ARN (which I guess is fine, though I'm not too sure on the stability of ARN formats)
- listing all clusters (`aws ecs list-clusters`), then describing services (`aws ecs descibe-service --cluster cluster-1 --services arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:service/cluster-1/example-service` ) for every cluster

I feel like I must be missing something!

Comment: arn formats are extremely stable. Changing the arn format would e.g. destroy all IAM policies, that must not happen.

Comment: Looks like ECS ARN format did change 2 years ago, but hopefully for the last time :D https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-your-amazon-ecs-deployment-to-the-new-arn-and-resource-id-format-2/.